# Demonstration of a simple formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

The course I'm studying, showed me two simple demonstrations that led to arithmetic sum $S_n=\dfrac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$, and geometric sum $S_n=a\dfrac{q^{n}-1}{q-1}$

Now, in an exercise that  asked to find the number of terms, $n$, knowing the first term $a_1$, the last term $a_n$, and the common ratio $d$, I used  numerical examples, and I deduced the general formula to find n:
$$n=\dfrac{a_n-a_1}{d}+1$$
Is there a demonstration that leads to this last formula? If yes, could you show it to me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's an error for the sum of the geometric sum: the numerator is $q^n-1$. The value of $n$ is to be found for what type of sum?

Comment: Sum of geometric series should be $S_{n} = \frac{a(q^n - 1)}{q-1}$, $q \neq 1$.

Comment: I think that $d$ is actually common difference and not common ratio. In which case, what you are moving forward to prove is, in fact, true by definition of an arithmetic series

Comment: @ Bernard: Edited. the last formula is related to arithmetic sum. Thank you very much.

Comment: In your question, you mean common difference $d$. Then let $n$ be the number of terms. We have $a_n=a_1+d(n-1)$, From this, algebraic manipulation gives your formula.

Comment: @Yes, this is it! Thank you very much. By the way some mistakes and inaccuracies in my side come from translation, as English isn't my language.